# cant figure out d3.js error

Tags: javascript, d3.js

```js
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    
var x = d3.scaleBand()
          .range([0, width])
          .padding(0.1);
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
          .range([height, 0]);
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
       
var temp = [ {"Gender":"Male","count":5}, {"Gender":"Female","count":2}];
var data=[]
data.push(temp);

 x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Gender; }));
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.count; })]);
  
    svg.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(data)
      .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("x", function(data) { return x(data.Gender); })
        .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(data.count); })
        .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(data.count); });


    svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x));


    svg.append("g")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
```

```css
<style> /* set the CSS */

.bar { fill: steelblue; }

</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body><script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script></body>
```

I want a graph to plot male and female count. count in y-axis and gender in x-axis
my d3.js index.html

where data_json is the this data
`[ {"Gender":"Male","count":5}, {"Gender":"Female","count":2}];`

im getting graph for only 1 set i.e  `{"Gender":"Male","count":5}` if i set data_json to the same else only axis is displayed.

but not together in same graph. Im new to d3.js and unable to figure out the solution. please help.

Comment: Your code seems to be broken. Can you make a codepen or fiddle ?

Comment: i have done it. Please help if you can:) Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is stems from this:

```
var temp = [ {"Gender":"Male","count":5}, {"Gender":"Female","count":2}];
var data=[]
data.push(temp);
```

The d3 `.data` method takes an array. Combined with an enter selection, one element can be appended per item in the array. `temp` is already an array, by pushing it to `data` you are making an array like the follows:

```
[[ {"Gender":"Male","count":5}, {"Gender":"Female","count":2}]]
```

This array has only one item, a sub-array. The sub-array is really what you want though. This is also creates problems when using the scales:

```
x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Gender; }));
```

As each datum (and there is only one) comprises of an array, `d.Gender` will be undefined, `d[1]` will be defined.

Instead, use your temp array as your dataset without pushing it into a new array. Then modify the y, x, and height values of each rect to access `d.count` or `d.Gender` rather than `data.Gender` or `data.count` (as `data.count` is undefined, and also not datum specific, while `d.count` is the count associated with the datum bound to each rect).

Take a look at the snippet below which makes these changes:

```js
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    
var x = d3.scaleBand()
          .range([0, width])
          .padding(0.1);
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
          .range([height, 0]);
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
       
var data = [ {"Gender":"Male","count":5}, {"Gender":"Female","count":2}];


 x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Gender; }));
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.count; })]);
  
    svg.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(data)
      .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("x", function(data) { return x(data.Gender); })
        .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.count); })
        .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.count); });


    svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x));


    svg.append("g")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
```

```css
<style> /* set the CSS */

.bar { fill: steelblue; }

</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body><script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script></body>
```

Comment: Thankyou so much @Andrew reid. It was a big help!:)